# bitwise array manipulation with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to translate the following C++ expression

```
(i0?8:0) | (i1?4:0) | (i2?2:0) | (i3?1:0)
```

to python, where `i0`, `i1`, `i2`, and `i3` are `numpy.ndarray`s of bool (obtained via expressions like `i0 = x < y`). What is the most efficient way to achieve that? My naive approach is

```
np.where(i0,8,0) | np.where(i1,4,0) | np.where(i2,2,0) |  np.where(i3,1,0)
```

but is there are faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `i0`/`i1`/`i2`/`i3` arrays of booleans you can use:

```
out = 8*i0 + 4*i1 + 2*i2 + i3
```

Comment: This is definitely faster than my original approach and seems to be correct too!

Comment: @Walter thanks for the feedback. If efficiency is your main goal I encourage you to test Jérôme's answer as it has multiple levels of optimization.

Comment: (I needed to repost my comment to fix a typo)

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- use `view` so to convert booleans to 1-byte integer values without any copy;
- compute the operation using 1-byte integer (faster for large arrays since they take less space in RAM and the CPU caches);
- replace `np.where` with shifts that are generally a bit faster to compute (thanks to SIMD instructions);
- perform in-place computation thanks to the third parameter (`out`) of many Numpy functions so to avoid creating useless **temporary arrays**

Here is the resulting code:

```py
def compute_faster(i0, i1, i2, i3):
    tmp1 = np.left_shift(i0.view(np.uint8), np.uint8(3))
    tmp2 = np.left_shift(i1.view(np.uint8), np.uint8(2))
    np.bitwise_or(tmp1, tmp2, tmp1)
    np.left_shift(i2.view(np.uint8), np.uint8(1), tmp2)
    np.bitwise_or(tmp1, tmp2, tmp1)
    np.bitwise_or(tmp1, i3.view(np.uint8), tmp1)
    return tmp1
```

I assume the input values are boolean-typed array since `x < y` return such an array. Note that the output is an uint8-typed array (so you should care with overflows and signed values regarding what you do with it or you can just convert it or an int32-typed array to be safe at the expense of a slower computation).

This is certainly the best solution using only Numpy. For faster performance, you certainly need to use a native compiled code. **Numba** and **Cython** are a good way to speed this up. Here is a solution using Numba:

```py
import numba as nb

# Assume the input arrays are contiguous. 
# Please use bool_[:] otherwise
@nb.njit('(bool_[::1], bool_[::1], bool_[::1], bool_[::1])')
def compute_fastest(i0, i1, i2, i3):
    out = np.empty(i0.size, dtype=np.uint8)
    ui0 = i0.view(np.uint8)
    ui1 = i1.view(np.uint8)
    ui2 = i2.view(np.uint8)
    ui3 = i3.view(np.uint8)
    for i in range(i0.size):
        # `+` is faster than `|` since `|` is not a bitwise operator in Python and Numba keep its semantic.
        # This enable the compiler to generate fast SIMD instructions
        out[i] = (ui0[i] << np.uint8(3)) + (ui1[i] << np.uint8(2)) + (ui2[i] << np.uint8(1)) + ui3[i]
    return out
```

---

### Performance results

Here are performance results with arrays of size 4096 on my i5-9600KF processor using Numpy 1.24.3:

```
reference code:    27.2 µs
compute_faster:    17.7 µs
compute_fastest:    1.5 µs
```

The Numba code is certainly very close to be optimal for quite short arrays. For very short ones, Cython should be better due to a possibly lower overhead. For very large arrays, you can use multiple threads (using the `parallel=True` flag and `nb.prange` instead of `range`).

Comment: Okay, I'm not relying on numba, as it usually is one or two versions behind.

Comment: Numba is not the only version provided in the answer. The Numpy version (`compute_faster`) is faster than all other answers on my machine.

Answer (score -1):

You could used bitwise operators:

```
out = (i0<<3) | (i1<<2) | (i2<<1) | (i3<<0)
```